# Spring roo working

Tags: spring-roo

Anybody worked in Spring Roo????? I am new to spring roo... So need some help on how to build applications in roo... I tried for the tutorial on springsource... But is thr any more source or examples for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The pizza-tutorial on the website covers the most basic.

There's also a wedding-tutorial here: http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2/

Comment: i have gone through these tutorials.... i want some reference in terms broader perspective... may be some html forms, form actions.. in that way....eg a normal login logout application wherein it talks to database.... i want something that will help me build such an application...

Answer (score 0):

(Only one ahref per post for new users...)

Here is a good place for learning basic spring: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

To get full benefit of Roo it's important to understand how spring works.

Comment: That appears to be very true, but seems to negate the benefit of Roo as a sort of easy to use app. I wish there was more documentation on taking your Roo project to the next level... I think that just might be: "remove your project from Roo and start using/learning Spring!"

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start with the small application tutorial at: http://www.springsource.org/roo/start and then proceed furhter with the links give under Next Steps in the same page at the bottom. Also you can search for spring roo on youtube for few video tutorials.